# How To Send ETH without communing TX on blockchain (via Smart Contract)

Tags: contract-development, transactions, blockchain, security, privacy

Is there anyway to send some ether without committing transaction in blockchain using Smart Contract?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This questions is unspecific. You can transfer ether to a contract address and then to an address owned by a user. But you always need a transaction to transfer ether, no matter if you transfer it to a contract address by calling a `payable` method of a contract, or by directly transferring it through a direct transaction between two human owned accounts.

Whenever you need a state change (and transacting ether is a state change because one address has less and the other address has more afterwards) you need a transaction. The only way to "transfer" money to other people without a transaction is if you give them your account.